# how to find the list of different geoms and aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to find the list of aesthetics and geoms in the `ggplot2` package for R and the problem that `help(qplot`) does not yield any results. I can not find a way to invoke help for only aesthetics or geoms.

What is the correct way to invoke help for aesthetics in R?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best approach I can think of is to look at `help(aes)` which gives links to

```
help(aes_colour_fill_alpha)
help(aes_group_order)
help(aes_linetype_size_shape)
help(aes_position)
```

Which summarize the various `aes` sub groups.

You would get to one of these if you were search for a particular `aes`theic (eg `help(alpha)` or `help(group)`

For a list of geoms, look at the index for the help, under `G`. Perhaps when the documentation for `layer` is completed (or started) it will spur a similar listing / sub grouping.

You could also extract the relevant exported objects within the ggplot2 namespace using

```
ls(pattern = '^geom_', env = as.environment('package:ggplot2'))

 ## [1] "geom_abline"     "geom_area"       "geom_bar"        "geom_bin2d"      "geom_blank"      "geom_boxplot"    "geom_contour"   
 ## [8] "geom_crossbar"   "geom_density"    "geom_density2d"  "geom_dotplot"    "geom_errorbar"   "geom_errorbarh"  "geom_freqpoly"  
## [15] "geom_hex"        "geom_histogram"  "geom_hline"      "geom_jitter"     "geom_line"       "geom_linerange"  "geom_map"       
## [22] "geom_path"       "geom_point"      "geom_pointrange" "geom_polygon"    "geom_quantile"   "geom_raster"     "geom_rect"      
## [29] "geom_ribbon"     "geom_rug"        "geom_segment"    "geom_smooth"     "geom_step"       "geom_text"       "geom_tile"      
## [36] "geom_violin"     "geom_vline"
```

`ggplot2` has an unexported character vector `.all_aesthetics` which contains all the possible aesthetics

```
ggplot2:::.all_aesthetics
```

Answer (score 7):

[The actual documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/) has a detailed and very handy list as well

```
 http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/
```