# ggplot: How to set default color for all geoms?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to set the default color for all geoms in a ggplot to something other than black. Note this is *not* about setting scale_color...

Simple example:

```
# linear model with confidence bands...
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=1:50, y=5 + 2*(1:50)+rnorm(50,sd=10))
lm <- lm(y~x,df)
se <- summary(lm)$sigma           # standard error of fit
Z  <- qnorm(0.05/2,lower.tail=F)  # 95% confidence bands
df <- cbind(df,predict(lm,se.fit=T)[c("fit","se.fit")])
# plot the result...
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=y), size=3) +
  geom_line(aes(y=fit)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=fit+Z*se.fit), linetype=2)+
  geom_line(aes(y=fit-Z*se.fit), linetype=2)
```

[image]

Now, suppose I want to make everything red. Leaving aside the advisability of doing that, I would think `ggplot(df, aes(x=x), colour="red")` would do it. But the `colour=` parameter seems to be ignored: everything is still black. I can add `colour="red"` to every `geom_` call, but I'm trying to avoid that.

**Edit:** 
Using `ggplot(df, aes(x=x, color="red"))` is not an option because it creates a *color scale* using the default ggplot palette ([evenly spaced around an HSL color circle](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_%28ggplot2%29/)). With one color, this is `#F8766D`, which happens to be light red. In addition, this creates a legend which then must be hidden.

Comment: Just curiously, why do you not want to use scale_color_?

Comment: @PirateGrunt The edit at the end of the question kind of explains it. I would have to create a color scale by setting a color in `aes(...)` in the ggplot call, then use something like `scale_color_manual(values="red", guide="none")`. It's just a hack  - there should be an easier way. Plus, suppose I want to use a color scale for something else in the plot, say color the points based on some grouping variable and make everything else red.

Comment: @PirateGrunt another reason would be for dark themed plots. There the only challenge is to set the geom related color (dots, box plots, lines etc.)

Answer (score 32):

You can set a default color for each geometry type this way:

```
update_geom_defaults("point",   list(colour = "red"))
update_geom_defaults("line",   list(colour = "red"))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=y), size=3) +
  geom_line(aes(y=fit)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=fit+Z*se.fit), linetype=2)+
  geom_line(aes(y=fit-Z*se.fit), linetype=2)
```

**Edit** 
 If you want to do to everything then use (Edit borrow from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15890957/1000343)):

```
params <- ls(pattern = '^geom_', env = as.environment('package:ggplot2'))
geoms <- gsub("geom_", "", params)

lapply(geoms, update_geom_defaults, list(colour = "red"))
lapply(geoms, update_geom_defaults, list(fill = "red", colour = "red")) ## include fills
```

If you want to set the default colour for the just one plot, simply do:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, colour="red")) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=y), size=3) +
  geom_line(aes(y=fit)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=fit+Z*se.fit), linetype=2)+
  geom_line(aes(y=fit-Z*se.fit), linetype=2)
```

Comment: Wow, I never knew about that function. Amazing.

Comment: Thanks but this is not quite what I was looking for. I'm trying to set the default color *for just this ggplot object*, in the same sense that calling `ggplot(df)` makes `df` the default dataset for this object. According to the documentation, `update_geom_default(...)` sets the defaults for all future plots in this session.

Comment: Amended to reflect that distinction. @Blue Magister, is the amendment what you suggested earlier? If so, please resubmit for attribution!

Comment: @metasequoia Amazing function! However, there is an issue with your code because it maps the colour aesthetic to a variable 'red', try changing it to 'green' and you'll see the lines and points are still colored red.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with multiple colors, for instance with geom_col when there are 3 categories.

Comment: @amzu though `aes(colour = "red")` doesn't throw any error, technically it is wrong. It assigns default `ggplot` color to all data and not red color. The alternative is `plot + scale_color_manual( breaks = NULL , values = "red")`

Answer (score 2):

In order to replace a geom default aesthetic with another one (for all geoms using that aesthetic), you can try the following code.

First define a function for getting default aes settings of all geoms from *ggplot2*

```
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

geom_aes_defaults <- function() {
  geom_names <- apropos("^Geom", ignore.case = FALSE)
  geoms <- mget(geom_names, env = asNamespace("ggplot2"))
  map(geoms, ~ .$default_aes)
}
```

With `geom_aes_defaults()` you obtain a long list of all geom aesthetic mappings

```
$Geom
Aesthetic mapping:
<empty>

$GeomAbline
Aesthetic mapping:
* `colour`   -> "black"
* `size`     -> 0.5
* `linetype` -> 1
* `alpha`    -> NA

$GeomAnnotationMap
Aesthetic mapping:
* `colour`   -> "NA"
* `fill`     -> "grey20"
* `size`     -> 0.5
* `linetype` -> 1
* `alpha`    -> NA

$GeomArea
Aesthetic mapping:
* `colour`   -> NA
* `fill`     -> "grey20"
* `size`     -> 0.5
* `linetype` -> 1
* `alpha`    -> NA

...
```

The following function iterates over all geoms matching a given aesthetic and substitutes the corresponding values

```
replace_geom_aes_defaults <- function(name, old_aes, new_aes) {
  matching_geoms <- 
    map(geom_aes_defaults(), name) %>%
      compact() %>%
      keep(~ !is.na(.) & . == old_aes)
  geoms <- gsub("^Geom(.*)", "\\1", names(matching_geoms))
  walk(geoms, update_geom_defaults, setNames(list(new_aes), name))
}
```

Now you can replace colors systematically, e.g. turn black into red by

```
replace_geom_aes_defaults("colour", "black", "red")
```

or even replace fill colors (for bar plots) by

```
replace_geom_aes_defaults("fill", "grey35", "red")
```