# scale_fill_manual is not working in geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to change the color in a barplot in ggplot2 using scale_fill_manual, but for some reason only works if i use the fill option inside aesthetics.
I made an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr) 
iris %>% ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Width,y=Sepal.Length))+
geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_fill_manual(values='lightblue')
```

Here is the result, no changing in the color:
[image]

Now, using the fill option inside aesthetics, it works:

```
iris %>% ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Width,y=Sepal.Length, fill=factor(2) ))+
geom_bar(stat="identity")+scale_fill_manual(values='lightblue')
```

[image]

There is some way to change the bar colour without using the fill option, only using scale_fill_manual?

Comment: `scale_fill_manual` will work only if you have a `fill` aesthetic inside `aes`. But if you don't want to map a data column to the fill aesthetic, why not just set the fill color inside `geom_bar`: `geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="lightblue")`?

Comment: Remember that `aes()` _maps_ aesthetics, but you can _set_ them using normal function arguments.

Comment: I have the same question. Let's say I am creating a "theme" and want the default color of the bars to be blue. I want to theme to automate that, even  if the user has not declared a fill variable.

Comment: I posted a similar question here: https://github.com/jrnold/ggthemes/issues/67   (no answer yet though)

Comment: @LucasMation, does [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21175042/496488) answer your question?

Comment: @eipi10, Awesome! Tks!

Comment: @eipi10, for this example your suggestion works fine, but my goal is change de color without using a fill option, in any part of the code.
That's because i've already a personal pallete, so my ideia is that the user doesn't have to worry about choosing any color, he will only have to add "+ personal_pallete" in the script, where:

cbPalette <- c('#003576','#006EAB','#9CD2EB','#000000','#7D7D7D','#C8C8C8')
personal_pallete<- list(scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette),scale_colour_manual(values=cbPalette)).

That's why i need to change the color only using scale_fill_manual. Any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry @eipi10, didn't see your suggestion to LucasMation, i'm gonna try this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define `fill` inside your `aes` .