# Change geom default aesthetics as part of theme component only

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

For a custom `ggplot2` theme I'd like to change the default aesthetic of some `geom`, say I want red dots instead of black dots.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21175042/8583393) I know we can change defaults for a `geom` using the function `update_geom_default` but I wonder if it is possible to change the colour only when we call `theme_red_dots`?

Example of my naive attempt:

```
library(ggplot2)

theme_red_dots <- function(...) {
  update_geom_defaults("point", list(colour = "red"))
  theme_minimal() +
    theme(...)
}
```

Looks good here:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_red_dots()
```

[image]

But I'd like the points to be black again when I call

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

---

Below is an example of why I thought this could be useful. We can change `panel.background` to be black fairly easy but this would make it impossible to see the points if we don't map an aesthetic to colour. (The usefulness of this `theme_black` can certainly be discussed, but I would like to avoid an argument about that.)

```
theme_black <- function(...) {
  theme_minimal() +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black")) +
    theme(...)
}

# update_geom_defaults("point", list(colour = "black"))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_black()
```

[image]

Changing the colour of the points inside `geom_point()` is an option here (see @zx8754 answer), but this requires the user of `theme_black()` to change it, while I am wondering if there is a way to do this right inside `theme_*`.

Comment: Why change defaults? Maybe just make red dots within `theme_red_dots`

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but, I did some research by looking at how `ggthemr` did it, and they too are using `update_geom_defaults` (line 54 https://github.com/cttobin/ggthemr/blob/master/R/ggthemr.R), so probably it is the only way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The released version of **ggplot2** doesn't currently offer a way to do this. However, this is [a fairly old feature request](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2239) and has been [under development](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/2749) since the summer of 2018.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to detach and reattach `ggplot2` (apparently you can do this within custom `ggplot2` theme function).

```
library(ggplot2)

theme_red_dots <- function(...) {
    # wanted theme
    update_geom_defaults("point", list(colour = "red"))

    # Plot
    p <- theme_minimal() + 
        theme(...)

    # Detach and reattach ggplot2
    detach("package:ggplot2", unload = TRUE); library(ggplot2)

    # Return wanted plot
    return(p)
}
# red dots
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    theme_red_dots()
# black (default) dots
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
    geom_point()
```

Works with wanted `theme_black` too:

```
theme_black <- function(...) {
    update_geom_defaults("point", list(colour = "red"))
    p <- theme_minimal() +
        theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black")) +
        theme(...)
    detach("package:ggplot2", unload = TRUE); library(ggplot2)
    return(p)
}

# Plots with black background
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    theme_black()

# Plots with default background
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
    geom_point()
```

Comment: Really interesting! I'm surprised this works. Would have assumed re-attaching **ggplot2** would have reset the default colour also for the existing plots.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing defaults, make custom *geom_point*:

```
library(ggplot2)

# make custom geom with red as default
geom_point_red <- function()geom_point(col = "red")

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  geom_point_red()
```

Answer (score 2):

As my reputation won't allow me to comment:

@PoGibas:
An issue about detaching and re-attaching `ggplot2` is that if other packages are loaded that require it, e.g. `rstan`, it won't work and return an error.