# ggpubr: change the label shapes stroke

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, ggpubr

I am using `ggline()` function from `ggpubr` to create a line plot with mean and SD.
I would like to increase the thickness of my shapes. in `ggplot` it's usually done through `geom_point(stroke=)` but it doesn't work with `ggline`!
Does anyone has an idea how to do it?

```
ggline(iris, x = "Species", y = "Sepal.Length", add = "mean_se",
       color = "Species",shape = 7,size = 1,point.size=3,palette = c("black", "blue","red"),width=10,geom_point(stroke=1)
       )
```

I would like to have the squares thicker:
[image: I would like to have the squares thicker]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to update the geom defaults.. don't really see a way to

First something to keep the defaults, so that you can restore them (from [ggplot: How to set default color for all geoms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174625/ggplot-how-to-set-default-color-for-all-geoms)):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

geom_aes_defaults <- function() {
  geom_names <- apropos("^Geom", ignore.case = FALSE)
  geoms <- mget(geom_names, env = asNamespace("ggplot2"))
  map(geoms, ~ .$default_aes)
}

old = geom_aes_defaults()$GeomPoint
```

Now for your plot:

```
update_geom_defaults("point", list(stroke = 1.5))
ggline(iris, x = "Species", y = "Sepal.Length", add = "mean_se",
       color = "Species",shape = 7,size = 1,point.size=3,
       palette = c("black", "blue","red"),width=10
)
```

And we restore the default:

```
update_geom_defaults("point", list(stroke = old$stroke))
# you can also do
#update_geom_defaults("point", list(stroke = 1))
```